# When would one use mysqli_ping?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having trouble understanding an example of when this function would be used, and how it would be implemented. Could anyone provide some clarity on the subject? The php manual provides this information but I'd really appreciate it if someone could break it down "barney style" for me.

Thanks in advance.

> Checks whether the connection to the server is working. If it has gone down, and global option mysqli.reconnect is enabled an automatic reconnection is attempted.
>
> This function can be used by clients that remain idle for a long while, to check whether the server has closed the connection and reconnect if necessary.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php

Comment: It doesn't get as *"Barney"* then that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have an PHP-Job that is running from an crontab under linux.
And the script maybe takes a long time to run.
Plus the script is runnnig more than one time at the same time.

Whitin the script you connect to your DB at the beginning, then the script does a lot of work (maybe download large data, prepare large data ....) and it is here and there using the database. But in same cases the database connection is lost because of too long idle time (Database Configuration). Some script maybe need 1 min. to download and another istance needs more than 5 hours.

Here comes the mysqli_ping function and handles that. Instead of allways reconnect to the database (before each query, to be really really sure its connected) the mysql_ping can test the connection if still working. if not you can then reconnect the connection.

Topic here: max_connction_timeout, max_allowed_connection, max_idle_time

see MYSQL Pages

Kindly, Barney

Answer (score 0):

if you have a long-running script, for an example some back-end process such as cron job where there could be a time span between connecting and applying queries, `mysqli_ping` comes handy in checking db connection availability.